# SSIS package fails to run on SQL SERVER AGENT as job

Tags: ms-access, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I have a job running on SQL SERVER 2012 that i created on SSIS. That job pull some data from an access database due to an ODBC connection and load a local db. The access database is located in a different server from the SQL SERVER and both of the servers have x86 structure. The thing is that when run the job in SSIS everything works fine, but in SQL SERVER AGENT keeps given me error!!

Following the error message:

> 01/14/2016 12:49:15,carrega_hlr_join_atem,Error,1,W7RJO071543,carrega_hlr_join_atem,Exec Package,,Executed with user: EMBRATEL\EGSANTO. Utilitário de Execução de Pacotes do Microsoft (R) SQL Server  Versão 11.0.5058.0 para 32 bits  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.    Início: 12:49:15  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.12     Code: 0xC0014020     Origem: Package Gerenciador de conexões "TB_HLR"     Descrição: Error de ODBC -1.  End of Error  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Code: 0xC0014009     Origem: Package Gerenciador de conexões "TB_HLR"     Descrição: Error when trying to establish an ODBC connection to the database server.  End of Error  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Code: 0x0000020F     Origem: Task data flow NeFone (Access) [67]     Descrição: Failed call to AcquireConnection method for connection manager TB_HLR with the Code de Error 0xC0014009. Talvez haja mensagens de Error postadas antes desta com mais informações sobre o motivo da falha na chamada de método AcquireConnection.  End of Error  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Code: 0xC0047017     Origem: Task data flow SSIS.Pipeline     Descrição: Fail on validating NeFone (Access) with the Code de Error 0x80004005.  End of Error  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Code: 0xC004700C     Origem: Task data flow SSIS.Pipeline     Descrição: Falha na validação de um ou mais componentes.  End of Error  Error: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Code: 0xC0024107     Origem: Task data flow      Descrição: Houve Errors durante a validação da tarefa.  End of Error  DTExec: a execução do pacote retornou DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Início: 12:49:15  Conclusão: 13:06:34  Tempo decorrido:  1038.37 segundos.  Falha na execução do pacote.  A etapa falhou.,00:17:19,0,0,,,,0

PS.: The Error Message is originally in portuguese, i've tried to translate some of the errors but, been my english kind poor, i will gladly try to explain the others messages if anyone has issues to identify the error by the code.

Can anyobody help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify ODBC connection driver at server SSIS. If not exists, try install it, or change connection to ADO DB, is faster.

I had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem working with MySQL ODBC driver.  When i use it from SSDT or SSIS Catalog, the package works fine. But when I try to execute it from SQL Server Agent, It didn't work. 
The reason,  my sql server agent was running with an unmanagment account like DESKTOP\SQL_Agent.  these account really don't exists, and it doesn't have permission to get ODBC DNS information.
To repair these condition, use the following steps:
1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, change the account of the service SQL Server Agent for an Windows Account.  I use one with local administrator permisions.
2. Restart the service.
3. In the properties of the job step, that are invoking the ETL, in the advanced properties, choose runtime in 32bit.
4. Execute the job again